# Securitycontext across multiple containers

Tags: java, security, spring-security, cas, josso

I have two apps, app1 is running using multiple jars inside a war and uses spring security(digest) for authentication. app1 runs in tomcat, and i have another app running in another web container (glassfish) app2. app2 uses form based authentication. Both the apps use same username and password, i need to authenticate app1 from app2 and have the authentication results in a securitycontext. I have searched, but couln't find much info. Have some across similar scenario?? Any information will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a single sign on solution. [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/features.html) has some basic SSO capabilities, but for a more robust tool you should check out [JOSSO](http://www.josso.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Spring also support integration with [Central Authentication Service (CAS)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html).

There is an extension for [SAML](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/extensions/saml/index.html).

And another extension for [OAuth](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/).

Any of them could give you autentication across multiple apps.